# How to repeat rows by their value by multiple columns and divide back

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0), C=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0), D=c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1))
> df
  A B C D
1 1 0 1 0
2 2 0 0 2
3 3 3 0 0
4 4 0 1 0
5 5 0 0 1
```

How would I go about converting it to:

```
  A B C D
1 1 0 1 0
2 2 0 0 1
3 2 0 0 1
4 3 1 0 0
5 3 1 0 0
6 3 1 0 0
7 4 0 1 0
8 5 0 0 1
```

As you can see there are value `2` and `3`, I want to repeat them by that length and change the values back to 1. How would I do that?

I also want to duplicate the the `A` column as you can see.

I tried:

```
replace(df[rep(rownames(df), select(df, -A)),], 2, 1)
```

But it gives me an error.

Comment: So you want to duplicate values in column B, C and D ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes! and also duplicate A, but on the B C and D columns I want the values to be evenly divided to become 1.

Comment: For a row would there always be only 1 value which is not 0 , ignoring column A ofcourse.

Comment: @RonakShah yes, correct!

Comment: another one: `df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), rowSums(df[2:4])), ]; df[2:4] <- +!!df[2:4]; df`

Comment: @rawr Just that doesn't floor the values 1, and if you could add that you could post an answer

Comment: @U12-Forward which part are you looking at? the result i get is the same as the one below

Comment: @rawr The values should be come 1, not continue to be `3` or `2`.

Comment: thats what this part does `df[2:4] <- +!!df[2:4]`

Comment: @rawr Oh a typo from my end! That works! You should post as an answer, btw I just posted one too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to get max value from columns `B`, `C` and `D` using `pmax`, use `uncount` to repeat the rows. Use `pmin` to replace the values greater than 1 to 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(repeat_row = pmax(B, C, D)) %>%
  uncount(repeat_row) %>%
  mutate(across(-A, pmin, 1))

#  A B C D
#1 1 0 1 0
#2 2 0 0 1
#3 2 0 0 1
#4 3 1 0 0
#5 3 1 0 0
#6 3 1 0 0
#7 4 0 1 0
#8 5 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, there's just one value > 0 in columns B to D, so we can exploit the partial `rowSums` for a `replicate` call on columns B to D binarized using `> 0`. So that we can use this in `Map`, we `t`ranspose twice. Rest is cosmetics.

```
t(do.call(cbind, Map(replicate,
                     rowSums(df[-1]), 
                     as.data.frame(t(cbind(df[1], df[-1] > 0)))))) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(names(df))
#   A B C D
# 1 1 0 1 0
# 2 2 0 0 1
# 3 2 0 0 1
# 4 3 1 0 0
# 5 3 1 0 0
# 6 3 1 0 0
# 7 4 0 1 0
# 8 5 0 0 1
```

**Note:** R>=4.1 used.

Comment: @U12-Forward The `|>` is the new base R pipe which works similar to the magrittr `%>%` pipe but is much faster. See [there](https://michaelbarrowman.co.uk/post/the-new-base-pipe/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to modify Ronak Shah's answer a bit, I realized you could simply just do it with only `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df[rep(rownames(df), apply(select(df, -A), 1, max)),] %>%
  as.data.frame(row.names=1:nrow(.)) %>%
  mutate(across(-A, pmin, 1))
```

Output:

```
  A B C D
1 1 0 1 0
2 2 0 0 1
3 2 0 0 1
4 3 1 0 0
5 3 1 0 0
6 3 1 0 0
7 4 0 1 0
8 5 0 0 1
```

Or with `rowSums`:

```
library(dplyr)

df[rep(rownames(df), rowSums(select(df, -A)),] %>%
  as.data.frame(row.names=1:nrow(.)) %>%
  mutate(across(-A, pmin, 1))
```